# Java regexp - adding parenthesis makes it greedy?

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

```
public void name() throws Exception {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,2}?");
        String input = "09";
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println("match = "+m.group());
        }
    }
```

Output of the above method is :

```
match = 0
match = 9
```

Now, I am just adding parenthesis to the regexp:

```
public void name() throws Exception {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,2})?");
        String input = "09";
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println("match = "+m.group());
        }
    }
```

And the output becomes:

```
match = 09
match =
```

1. Why do parenthesis make the matching **greedy** here?
2. [Edit,added later]Why is empty string not matched in the first case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for a quantifier (`?`, `*`, `+` or `{n,m}`) to be reluctant (non-greedy or lazy), it must by followed by a `?`. Therefore, the pattern `\\d{1,2}?` is reluctant.

On the other hand, `(\\d{1,2})?` is composed of *two levels of greedy quantifiers*:

1. a group `(\\d{1,2})` containing a pattern with a greedy quantifier `{1,2}`,
2. followed by the `?` greedy quantifier.

Therefore, `(\\d{1,2})?` is greedy because the `?` does not **immediately** follow a quantifier (there is a parenthesis in between that closes the group), hence it does **not** act as the metacharacter for a reluctant regex.

See [this page about quantifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) as a reference.

Comment: I have already upvoted this answer due to the url, but could you elaborate a bit more on the topic?

Comment: Yes, even I would request you to elaborate further.

Comment: Just edited the question, Why is empty string not matched in the first case?

Comment: I elaborated on it. @dharm0us the pattern `\\d{1,2}?` is reluctant (lazy). The `?` in it does _not_ mean zero or one occurrence. So it will only match one digit. On the other hand, `(\\d{1,2})?` is greedy, so it will match two digits instead of one, then will match an empty string since the `?` in this case means zero or one occurrence.

Comment: @AR.3 Why does  the ? in it does not mean zero or one occurrence. You mean to say ? means 0 or 1 only when it isn't following a quantifier?

Comment: @dharm0us Exactly. A `?` right after a quantifier only makes that quantifier lazy.

Comment: @dharm0us I believe that AR has elaborated enough now. It would be kind of you to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with simple quantifier regex:

```
\d{1,2}
```

This is **greedy** by nature and will match as many characters as possible between `min` (i.e. `1`) and `max` (i.e `2`).

So for our input `09`, it will just match `09`.

Now let's make it **lazy** by using:

```
\d{1,2}?
```

This will make it **as few times as** possible. So for the same input it will match `0` first time and `9` second time (since you're using a `while` loop).

Now 3rd case of:

```
(\d{1,2})?
```

It matches 0 or 1 occurrence of greedy `\d{1,2}`, that means means match `\d{1,2}` or match nothing.

So for the same input it will match:

1. `09` or
2. empty string

It is because we are making whole group optional by placing `?` outside `(...)`